# RCA coax end termination

Tags: amplifier, circuit-design, audio, signal-integrity, coax

I am building an amplifier that takes in an RCA output from a TV. From my general understanding, RCA coaxial cables typically have an impedance of either 50 Ω or 75 Ω and a small amount of capacitance in the pF range, and require end termination to prevent signal 'bounce' (or reflection).

A couple of questions:

1. Is series or parallel termination with resistors (no isolation transformers used) better in terms of signal quality and latency/propagation?
2. What value resistor do I use for terminating 50 Ω or 75 Ω cables (single end termination only)?
3. Is it possible to design a termination circuit for both 50 Ω and 75 Ω cables? This is especially since my local store does not list impedances for generic RCA coax cables, nor have I found a reliable way to measure said cable.

Comment: Audio or video being transferred over RCA cables? Only quality RCA video and digital audio cables are coax with a specific impedance.

Comment: How long is your cable - source to destination?

Comment: And I think those so-called RCA coax cables are just ill defined shielded cables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*"RCA output"* is a bit vague but this answer assumes you're trying to handle *video* signals. The answers are mostly valid for audio signals as well, it would just be unusual or audiophile-grade weird. If your TV has audio outputs through RCA connectors they are likely *not* designed for a terminated receiver!

1. Since you only have control of the *sink* (as opposed to the *source*; you're at the receiving end) you can and must do parallel termination. Video transmission depends on it, and the source assumes it.
2. The values must equal the impedance. (but don't obsess about sub-percentage tolerances)
3. To my knowledge there are no consumer or professional video applications with 50 Ω impedance. It's all 75 Ω, so don't bother trying to do both. If you don't know, assume it's 75 Ω.

If you have an oscilloscope you should be able to measure the impedance (and length!) of an unknown cable.

Comment: I do have a (digital)oscilloscope. By measuring impedance, do you mean using the 'measure' menu(a common feature of digital oscilloscopes) or running a square wave through it and observing the change(or some more complex circuit)?

Comment: @lemon I was thinking just a square wave. If you look at the open end without any matching you should be able to see the reflections easily with the right settings. Then just try either 50 or 75 ohm termination and see which one removes the reflections better. Requires some thinking about what the "right settings" are, but that's the fun (and educational) part.